# Scapy - Incorrect Count of HTTP response codes

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap, http-response-codes

I am using Scapy to count occurrences of different HTTP response codes in a pcap file. Below is my code:

```
HTTP_STATUS_CODES={"200":0,"300":0,"301":0, "302":0,"304":0,"307":0,
               "400":0,"401":0, "403":0,"404":0,"410":0,"429":0,"500":0,"501"
               :0, "503":0,"550":0}

for pkt in PcapReader(pcap):
            if HTTP in pkt:
                if HTTPResponse in pkt:
                    status = pkt[HTTPResponse].Status_Code
                    if str(status) in HTTP_STATUS_CODES:
                        HTTP_STATUS_CODES[str(status)]=HTTP_STATUS_CODES[str(status)]+1
```

Some codes are counted incorrectly like 200 and 304. In the pcap which I am reading, `200` comes `105` times but scapy is counting only 54 times. `304` occurrence is `3` times but scapy is counting `4` times. I am using filter `http.response.code==200` in wireshark. Is scapy skipping some packets or what?

EDIT:

This is my complete code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.http import *
from scapy.sessions import TCPSession
import re
import glob
import os
import csv

#global variables declaration

HTTP_STATUS_CODES={"200":0,"300":0,"301":0, "302":0,"304":0,"307":0,
               "400":0,"401":0, "403":0,"404":0,"410":0,"429":0,"500":0,"501"
               :0, "503":0,"550":0}
HTTP_STATUS_CODES_DEF={"200":"OK","300":"Multiple choices","301":"Moved permanently", "302":"Moved temporarily","304":"Not modified","307":"Temporary redirect",
               "400":"Bad request","401":"Unauthorized", "403":"Forbidden","404":"Not found","410":"Gone","429":"Too many requests","500":"Internal server error",
                   "501":"Not implemented", "503":"Service unavailable","550":"Permission denied"}


def process_pcap ():
        pcap="path_to_pcap"
        file_CODES=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pcap))[0]+".csv"
        for pkt in PcapReader(pcap):
            if HTTP in pkt:
                if HTTPResponse in pkt:
                    # status codes are only in responses
                    status = pkt[HTTPResponse].Status_Code
                    if str(status) in HTTP_STATUS_CODES:
                        print(str(status))
                        HTTP_STATUS_CODES[str(status)]=HTTP_STATUS_CODES[str(status)]+1



        w = csv.writer(open(file_CODES, "w"))
        for key, val in HTTP_STATUS_CODES.items():
            w.writerow([key, HTTP_STATUS_CODES_DEF[key],  val ])



process_pcap()
```

And [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zdO0rjazviy9RhtA_qTHuhms7SvHjfrC) is link of file that I am trying to parse.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the packet capture? This will help ensure this question is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RossJacobs Provided.

Comment: What are your Python and Scapy versions?

Comment: python:2.7.16 & scapy: 2.4.3. I have realized that for scapy `HTTP` is same as in wireshark `tcp.port==80 && HTTP`. Scapy is not considering those packets as HTTP which use ports other than `80`. Is it so?